# Including the variables in a global environment in a dataset

Tags: r, cbind

I have about 70 variables in the global environment in RStudio and would like to turn them into a data frame – one column for each variable. Each variable has a length of 1,500. Is there a way to quickly do this?

Comment: I'm suspect there's a fairly simple answer to this, but we need more information. Specifically, "add them to a data set" is kind of vague. Do you mean a data frame? Are the variables vectors? Is there a system to how those variables are named? Could you edit your question to include examples of the variables and the data frame in a way that let's us run and test solutions?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification, Joran. Does my edit help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

`data.frame(mget(ls()))`

I can break this down a bit...

`ls()` returns a character vector containing the names of all variables in the global environment.

`mget()` returns the values bound to names contained in a character vector. The values are returned as a named list.

`data.frame()` just converts the named list of vectors to a data.frame.

If you want to build the `data.frame` using only a subset of the names in the global environment, try the `pattern` argument in `ls()`.  For instance, to build a `data.frame` using only names that start with the letter "m":

`data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^m.*")))`